# WCF Service Application does not allow basic authentication configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, basic-authentication

I have a WCF service application which uses the .NET Fraweork 4.5.2 and an application pool which has `Managed pipeline mode` set to `Integrated`. I use basic authentication to consume this WCF service. I have deployed the application to two environments (`dev` and `qa`), in `dev` it works perfectly, but in `qa` I get the following error:

[image]

Below is the IIS Authentication configuration of the application:

[image]

And this is my `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding>
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyProject.IS01" 
                 behaviorConfiguration="ServiceWithMetaData">
            <endpoint name="Default" 
                address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                contract="MyProject.IIS01" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceWithMetaData">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment 
            aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

The first phrase of the message error is very stange for me. It said that the authentication is set to `Windows`, but as you can see in the second screenshot, Windows authentication is disabled.

Is missing something from the configuration? Should I activate some features on the server where IIS is hosted?

I mention that all problems that I found on google are related to anonymous authentication (not to basic authentication).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are missing the `BindingConfiguration` setting in your service endpoint and thus the configuration isn't applied at all. Change it like below

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="testbinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>
  <service name="MyProject.IS01" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceWithMetaData">
    <endpoint name="Default" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
 contract="MyProject.IIS01" bindingConfiguration="testbinding" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: The iniatial configuration had a binding name (I also had the `bindingConfiguration` atribute pointing to it) and I had the same error.

Comment: @roroinpho21, try the posted answer once first and if doesn't work then come back with the exact error message

Comment: I fixed the problem wit restart on application pool